# Как получить атрибут id, конкретного draggable пункта?

Tags: jquery-ui, javascript

Вообщем имеется плейлист с возможностью изменять порядок воспроизведения на основе jquery-ui библиотеки

```
<ul id="draggable">
<li id="Array4">Song 4</li>
<li id="Array5">Song 5</li>
<li id="Array2">Song 2</li>
<li id="Array0">Song 0</li>
</ul>
```

При окончание мелодии запускается js-скрипт для проигрывания следующей мелодии в списке и запуск функции (назовем ее changecss(item)) которая должна поменять css-стиль для этого id... в нее передается порядковый номер draggable-пункта допустим item=1; которой соответствует "Song 5" и id="Array5". 
Проблема заключена в том что я не понимаю как получить id от конкретного пункта... 
Я пробовал так `ul.draggable[1].attr('id')` и так `ul.item[1].draggable.attr('id')` и даже так `$(ui[1].draggable).attr('id')` и так `$(item[1].draggable).attr('id')`

не работает =(

Что я делаю не правильно? Как же все таки получить атрибут id, конкретного draggable пункта?

Answer (score 1):

ID элемента, который сейчас проигрывается, есть?
Если да, то

```
var new_id = document.querySelector('#' + id_current).nextElementSibling.id;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но сделал по другому: 

    playlist = $('#draggable');
    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
    }

Вроде работает, соответственно добавились ссылки '<a>' к '<li>'